# Mapping old to new URLs with external file - configuration invalid

Tags: nginx, mapping

I'm moving an old website to a new nginx based host. To preserve the URL (which completely changed) I have a file that lists the mapping. I want to use it with [map module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html).

Inside `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf http{ ... }` I refer to PERL and the lowercase function:

```
#Include PERL and have a function for lowercasing the incoming URL
perl_modules perl/lib;

    # function to lowercase incoming strings like the URL
    perl_set $uri_lowercase 'sub {
        my $r = shift;
        my $uri = $r->uri;
        $uri = lc($uri);
        return $uri;
    }';
```

My site configuration, which is in the file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/notessensei` (Thx Alexey to point that out) looks like:

```
server {
    listen www.notessensei.com:80;
    root /home/stw/www;
    index index.html;
    server_name www.notessensei.com notessensei.com;

    location / {
        map $uri_lowercase $new {
            include /home/stw/www/blognginx.map;
        }

        if ($new) {
                rewrite ^ $new redirect;
        }
    }

    error_page 404 /blog/404.html;

}
```

The mapping file `blognginx.map` looks like this:

```
/blog/d6plinks/shwl-6bv35s /blog/2005/04/garbage-in-.html;
/blog/d6plinks/shwl-6c6ggp /blog/2005/05/just-me.html;
/blog/d6plinks/shwl-6c6gh4 /blog/2005/05/it-is-quotmake-your-own-caption-quot-time.html;
/blog/d6plinks/shwl-6c997j /blog/2005/05/big-business-wwjd.html;
/blog/d6plinks/shwl-6ca5qb /blog/2005/05/domino-on-solaris-anyone.html;
/blog/d6plinks/shwl-6ce65j /blog/2005/05/going-places-vietnam.html;
/blog/d6plinks/shwl-6ce6c9 /blog/2006/02/umsys-as-old-as-unix-sort-of.html;
```

for about **1300** lines. When I do a `service nginx configtest` I get a **fail**. When I don't use the `include` statement I get an OK. Now I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a way to get a more verbose error, one that tells me **what** is wrong and *where*?
2. What is wrong? Do I need to change the content of the include file? Do I need to move the section?

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: `map` directive must be in `http` block.

Comment: Actually no. There is no http block in a custom config (the one in /etc/nginx/sites-available). It also doesn't need to sit in a server block if you want to use it for more than one of them

Comment: All custom configs are in `http` block (if we speak about standard nginx config layout). They are included inside `http` block in nginx.conf

Comment: You are right. I didn't make it clear that my site configuration sits in an external file that gets included. I'll change and try again.

Comment: Have you tried `nginx -t`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`map`](http://nginx.org/r/map) directive must be immediate child `http` block.

> syntax: map string $variable { ... }
>
> default: —
>
> **context: http**

In your case, you must place it beside `server` block, because you custom config file is included right inside `http` block in nginx.conf.

```
map $uri_lowercase $new {
  include /home/stw/www/blognginx.map;
}

server {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out, thx to Alexey's pointers. There was a 4 fold problem:

- the map statement wasn't at the right place, Alexey pointed that out
- the file had some errors inside (missing space in a few lines)
- the map sized were too small (see solution below)
- the `service nginx configtest` tells less than `nginx -t`, again Alexey pointed me there

Now my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` has 2 additional lines in the `http {}` section:

```
## Increase bucket for big redirects
map_hash_bucket_size 256;
map_hash_max_size 4092;
```

and the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/notessensei` file looks like this:

```
map $uri_lowercase $new {
    include /home/stw/www/blognginx.map;
}

server {
    listen www.notessensei.com:80;
    root /home/stw/www;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name www.notessensei.com notessensei.com;

    location / {
        if ($new) {
                return 301 $new;
        }
    }

    error_page 404 /blog/404.html;

}
```

If you want to see it in action, pick any blog entry from [wissel.net](http://www.wissel.net/blog) and apply the uri part to [notessensei.com](http://www.notessensei.com/blog) - works like a charm with > 1200 entries.